# XAMPP and Blender isn't running

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, xampp, blender

I'm trying to install XAMPP server and Blender on my PC (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and whenever I try and open it, it just doesn't open.. so I thought "ok fair enough, let's do this the hard way" and did it through terminal.. I did all the commands etc. and after clicking enter it just drops to a new line.. no "invalid syntax" malaki.

I'm guessing it's not my machine that's the problem so how do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the server's conf. Did you add or change anything?

Comment: @yaron160 Nope, just downloaded the files from their webby's, untarred the blender package and then tried opning both files, they do the loading icon but then nothing happens. Haven't deleted anything or changed any file extensions.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about what you entered in the terminal and what was the output? Try running `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: I typed the usual untar command and run commands (can't remember exactly), exec commands, sudo apt-get commands, etc.

Comment: And like I stated in the question there was no output, it just drops to a new line

Comment: Could you post what command you use to start XAMPP? There isn't a lot to go on right now. I've had a similar problem with Blender tar packages, but I just used "sudo apt-get install blender" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update everyone: To run them, go to Terminal, Change directory to the one with the file inside (for me /Desktop/) and do ./filename and it opens. Hope this helps anyone :D

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP SUGGESTIONS

This might be a permissions issue. Try this,

(64 bit)

```
sudo chown -hR your_user_name_here /opt/lampp/
chmod +x /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run 
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

(32 bit)

```
sudo chown -hR your_user_name_here /opt/lampp/
chmod +x /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run 
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run
```

BLENDER SUGGESTIONS

As for Blender, try `sudo apt-get install blender` instead of using the installer from the website.

Comment: blender isn't a tar file, it's just an installer,
I'll try your idea when I have the chance :)

Comment: @TreyTaylor sounds good. Thought from the question that you extracted blender installer from tar package. Hope the repository version works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some people prefer to download XAMPP 1.7.3 version as it doesn't run GUI interface and it is smaller to store on disk.
As for blender it is easy to install it from Ubuntu Software Center unless you are trying to obtain the latest version of it.